# Delete object in a bucket AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, versioning, bucket

I come to you guys, because I would like to remove an object in a bucket aws. I activated the versioning on that bucket.

The object looks like that :

```
{
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
            "LastModified": "2020-06-12T00:49:29.700Z",
            "IsLatest": true,
            "Owner": {
                "DisplayName": "XXX",
                "ID": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Key": "my_file",
            "VersionId": "null",
            "Size": 165439242240,
            "ETag": "\"445fea819ed9cf0f127a39c64ec0da22-309\""
        }
```

I tried :

```
aws s3api delete-object --bucket my_bucket --key my_file --version-id version_id
```

That command creates a Delete Marker object , when I delete that `Delete Marker` , I get my starting `my_file`.

What I want to do is deleting definitely that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To permanently delete versioned objects, you must use DELETE Object versionId.

```
aws s3api delete-object --bucket my_bucket --key my_file --version-id null
```

More on [delete object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/delete-object.html) in AWS CLI Command Reference

When you enable versioning on an existing bucket, objects that are already stored in the bucket are unchanged. The version IDs (null), contents, and permissions remain the same.

To remove an object try this:

```
aws s3 rm s3://mybucket/test.txt
```

Comment: That's what I did actually. But I can't specify the version_id because the value is "null" .

Comment: Well, then it might mean the file has been in the bucket before the versioning was enabled. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Actually, to delete that kind of file with `"VersionId": "null"` , I need to use `aws s3api delete-object --bucket my_bucket --key my_file --version-id null`